# Python: Create a zip file of all files ending with ".json" in a directory

Tags: python, zip

Let's say the directory is /Home/Documents/Test_files.

I would like to create a zip file of all the files ending with ".json" and if possible delete the files so that only the zip file is left

So far I have been able to create a zip file of all the files in the given path but when I use the line `zipf.write(file)` it throws the error "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: sample.json". However when I use `zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))` it does write the files but also the whole directory path which I don't want.

I just want to write the files themselves. When I use `print file` the correct files seemed to be printed so I don't know why I get the error that the file doesn't exist

Currently my code looks like this:

```
def create_zip(path,zipf):
    #path is the directory address (i.e. /Home/Documents/Test_files)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".json"):
                print file
                zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))
                #zipf.write(file)
```

I would also like to remove/delete the files after creating the zip file to save space.

Any help as to why this is happening would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `chdir` before adding it to zip file not to include the whole directory path and use `os.remove` to delete the files afterwards:

```
def create_zip(path,zipf):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".json"):
                chdir(root)
                zipf.write(file)
                os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python's ZipFile module, you can just specify the argument

```
arcname = archive name
```

in the write() method, as in:

```
    import os
    from zipfile import ZipFile

    def create_zip(path,zipf):
        #path is the directory address (i.e. /Home/Documents/Test_files)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(".json"):
                    print file
                    zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file), arcname=file)
                    os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
```